# C# - Getting flat many-to-many List of Objects into List of distinct combinations of two Lists of objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, loops

I cannot seem to grasp how to do this, nor find an easy way to explain it... so I hope this simplified example will make sense.

Being given a List<> of objects as such:

```
public class FlatManyToMany
{
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    public int BookPages { get; set; }
    public string ReaderName { get; set; }
    public int ReaderAge { get; set; }
}

var flatManyToMany = new List<FlatManyToMany>();

flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "How to Do This Double List", BookPages = 105, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "How to Do This Double List", BookPages = 105, ReaderName = "Bob", ReaderAge = 34 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "Gone With Jon Skeet", BookPages = 192, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "Gone With Jon Skeet", BookPages = 192, ReaderName = "James", ReaderAge = 45 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "Gone With Jon Skeet", BookPages = 192, ReaderName = "Brian", ReaderAge = 15 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "Why Is This So Hard?", BookPages = 56, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "Why Is This So Hard?", BookPages = 56, ReaderName = "James", ReaderAge = 45 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "Why Is This So Hard?", BookPages = 56, ReaderName = "Brian", ReaderAge = 15 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "Impostor Syndrome", BookPages = 454, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29 });
flatManyToMany.Add(new FlatManyToMany { BookTitle = "Self Doubt and You", BookPages = 999, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29 });
```

The result I need is a List of two Lists of objects as such:

```
public class ResultDoubleList
{
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
    public List<Reader> Readers { get; set; } = new List<Reader>();
}

public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Reader
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The Book should only show up once in the end result, but the Reader can show up many times.  Multiple books can be put together if they were read by the same readers.

Here's how I need the result:

```
List<ResultDoubleList> results = new List<ResultDoubleList>();

result(1):
Books
    How to Do This Double List  105
Readers
    Kyle    29
    Bob     34

result(2):
Books
    Gone With Jon Skeet     192
    Why Is This So Hard?    56
Readers
    Kyle    29
    James   45
    Brian   15

result(3):
Books
    Impostor Syndrome   454
    Self Doubt and You  999
Readers
    Kyle    29
```

So distinct combinations of Lists of Books and Lists of Readers is the end result.  The Book only shows up once, but the Readers can show up more than once.  Books with the exact same list of readers would be grouped together.

Even if someone can tell me what this type of final result is called, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think `ReaderAge` and `BookPages` need to be defined as an `int`.

Comment: @RufusL You're right.  My actual problem isn't about Books and Readers, so just an example to simplify the problem as much as I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with this lengthy LINQ query:

```
var result = flatManyToMany
    .GroupBy(f1 => (f1.BookTitle, f1.BookPages))
    .Select(g1 => (bookInfo: g1.Key,
                    readers:
                        g1.Select(f2 => new Reader { Name= f2.ReaderName, Age= f2.ReaderAge }),
                    readerKey:
                        String.Join("|", g1.Select(f3 => $"{f3.ReaderName}{f3.ReaderAge}"))))
    .GroupBy(a1 => a1.readerKey)
    .Select(g2 => new ResultDoubleList {
        Books = g2.Select(a2 => new Book {
                    Title = a2.bookInfo.BookTitle,
                    Pages = a2.bookInfo.BookPages
                }
            ).ToList(),
        Readers = g2.First().readers.ToList() // Any will do, since they have the same readers
    })
    .ToList();
```

The idea is to group twice. Once per book and once per reader group.

First, we group by the [ValueTuple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) `(f1.BookTitle, f1.BookPages)`. The advantage over creating a `Book` object is that the `ValueTuple` automatically overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. This is required for types used as key in a dictionary or lookup as `GroupBy` does. Alternatively, you could override these methods in the `Book` class and group by `Book` objects. If you have a unique book id, use this one instead.

Then we create a temporary result with `Select`. We create a tuple again having 3 fields. The tuple containing the book information, an enumerable of `Reader` objects and, finally, we create a string containing all the readers as a key that we will use later to group by unique reader groups. If you have a unique reader id, this one instead of name and age.

So far, we have an

```
IEnumerable<(
    (string BookTitle, int BookPages) bookInfo,
    IEnumerable<Reader> readers,
    string readerKey
)>
```

Now we group by `readerKey` and then create the list of `ResultDoubleList` objects.

If you have difficulties understanding the details, break up the LINQ query into several queries. By using the "Make explicit" refactoring, you can then see what type of result you got. (That's how I got the complex `IEnumerable<T>` from above.) This also allows you to inspect the intermediate results in the debugger.

---

This test...

```
int resultNo = 1;
foreach (ResultDoubleList item in result) {
    Console.WriteLine($"\r\nresult({resultNo++}):");
    Console.WriteLine("Books");
    foreach (var book in item.Books) {
        Console.WriteLine($"    {book.Title,-28} {book.Pages,3}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Readers");
    foreach (var reader in item.Readers) {
        Console.WriteLine($"    {reader.Name,-8} {reader.Age,2}");
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

... yields:

```
result(1):
Books
    How to Do This Double List   105
Readers
    Kyle     29
    Bob      34

result(2):
Books
    Gone With Jon Skeet          192
    Why Is This So Hard?          56
Readers
    Kyle     29
    James    45
    Brian    15

result(3):
Books
    Impostor Syndrome            454
    Self Doubt and You           999
Readers
    Kyle     29
```

Comment: I like this one.

Comment: You should sort parts of the readerKey, otherwise the result would be unpredictable.

Comment: By god this was it. You say "lenghty LINQ query" when you should have seen what I was trying... it was getting out of hand.  The real problem had about 5 properties for "Book" and 26 properties for "Reader" and this answer / logic scaled and solved my real problem as expected.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @AntonínLejsek, good point! The readers have the same order in the example data, but this could be different in real data sets.

Answer (score 0):

## A. With a string key for readers groups

```
var booksReadByGroups = flatManyToMany.GroupBy(a => a.BookTitle)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Book = new Book { Title = g.Key, Pages = g.Max(a => a.BookPages) },
        Readers = g.Select(a => new Reader { Name = a.ReaderName, Age = a.ReaderAge }).ToList()
    })
    .GroupBy(b => string.Join("+",b.Readers.OrderBy(r=>r.Name).ThenBy(r=>r.Age).Select(r => $"{r.Name}{r.Age}")))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Books = g.Select(b => b.Book),
        Readers = g.First().Readers
    })
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(booksReadByGroups));
```

The above produces (with some line manual breaking):

```
[{
    "Books":[
        {"Title":"How to Do This Double List","Pages":105}
    ],
    "Readers":[
        {"Name":"Kyle","Age":29},
        {"Name":"Bob","Age":34}
    ]
},{
    "Books":[
        {"Title":"Gone With Jon Skeet","Pages":192},
        {"Title":"Why Is This So Hard?","Pages":56}
    ],
    "Readers":[
        {"Name":"Kyle","Age":29},
        {"Name":"James","Age":45},{"Name":"Brian","Age":15}
    ]
},{
    "Books":[
        {"Title":"Impostor Syndrome","Pages":454},
        {"Title":"Self Doubt and You","Pages":999}
    ],
    "Readers":[
        {"Name":"Kyle","Age":29}
    ]
}]
```

## B. Shorter, but uglier

We need to `GroupBy` twice, but the first projection is not necessary, and one `Select` is enough.

```
var readerGroups = flatManyToMany.GroupBy(a => a.BookTitle)
    .GroupBy(g => string.Join("+",g.OrderBy(r=>r.ReaderName).ThenBy(r=>r.ReaderAge).Select(r => $"{r.ReaderName}{r.ReaderAge}")))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Books = g.Select( g2 => new Book { Title = g2.Key, Pages = g2.Max(a => a.BookPages) }),
        Readers = g.First().Select(a => new Reader { Name = a.ReaderName, Age = a.ReaderAge })
    });
```

## C. With `IEquatable`

This version is the longest, but arguably the most correct, as it leaves to the `Reader` class to decide what readers are considered equal.

```
class ReadersComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<Reader>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<Reader> a, List<Reader> b) => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(a, b); // Please note this doesn't order the lists so you either need to order them before, or order them here and implement IComparable on the Reader class
    public int GetHashCode(List<Reader> os)
    {
        int hash = 19;
        foreach (var o in os) { hash = hash * 31 + o.GetHashCode(); }
        return hash;
    }
}

public class Reader : IEquatable<Reader>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => (Name, Age).GetHashCode();
    public bool Equals(Reader other) => (other is null) ? false : this.Name == other.Name && this.Age == other.Age;
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Reader);
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
var actsOfReading = new[]{
    new Reading { BookTitle = "How to Do This Double List", BookPages = 105, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "How to Do This Double List", BookPages = 105, ReaderName = "Bob", ReaderAge = 34},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "Gone With Jon Skeet", BookPages = 192, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "Gone With Jon Skeet", BookPages = 192, ReaderName = "James", ReaderAge = 45},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "Gone With Jon Skeet", BookPages = 192, ReaderName = "Brian", ReaderAge = 15},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "Why Is This So Hard?", BookPages = 56, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "Why Is This So Hard?", BookPages = 56, ReaderName = "James", ReaderAge = 45},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "Why Is This So Hard?", BookPages = 56, ReaderName = "Brian", ReaderAge = 15},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "Impostor Syndrome", BookPages = 454, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29},
    new Reading { BookTitle = "Self Doubt and You", BookPages = 999, ReaderName = "Kyle", ReaderAge = 29}
};


var booksReadByGroups = actsOfReading.GroupBy(a => a.BookTitle)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Book = new Book { Title = g.Key, Pages = g.Max(a => a.BookPages) },
        Readers = g.Select(a => new Reader { Name = a.ReaderName, Age = a.ReaderAge }).ToList()
    })
    .GroupBy(b => b.Readers, new ReadersComparer())
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Books = g.Select(b => b.Book),
        Readers = g.First().Readers
    })
    .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(booksReadByGroups));
}
```

*Output (manually formatted)*

```
[{
 "Books": [{
 "Title": "How to Do This Double List", "Pages": 105 }
 ],
 "Readers": [{
 "Name": "Kyle", "Age": 29 }, {
 "Name": "Bob", "Age": 34 }
 ]
}, {
 "Books": [{
 "Title": "Gone With Jon Skeet", "Pages": 192 }, {
 "Title": "Why Is This So Hard?", "Pages": 56 }
 ],
 "Readers": [{
 "Name": "Kyle", "Age": 29 }, {
 "Name": "James", "Age": 45 }, {
 "Name": "Brian", "Age": 15 }
 ]
}, {
 "Books": [{
 "Title": "Impostor Syndrome", "Pages": 454 }, {
 "Title": "Self Doubt and You", "Pages": 999 }
 ],
 "Readers": [{
 "Name": "Kyle", "Age": 29 }
 ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the Book name and Reader names are IDs.

```
var results = flatManyToMany
.GroupBy(f => new { f.BookTitle, f.BookPages })
.Select(g => new
{
    Book = new Book() { Title = g.Key.BookTitle, Pages = g.Key.BookPages },
    Readers = g.Select(i => new Reader() { Name = i.ReaderName, Age = i.ReaderAge })
})
.GroupBy(i => string.Concat(i.Readers.Select(r => r.Name).Distinct()))
.Select(g => new ResultDoubleList()
{
    Books = g.Select(i => i.Book).ToList(),
    Readers = g.SelectMany(i => i.Readers).GroupBy(r => r.Name).Select(r => r.First()).ToList()
})
;
```

```
    foreach(var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result:");
        Console.WriteLine("\tBooks:");
        foreach(var b in result.Books)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{b.Title}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\tReaders:");
        foreach (var reader in result.Readers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{reader.Name}");
        }
    }
```